# Gradle multi module jar upgrading issue

Tags: java, gradle, multi-module

I have gradle multi module project like below.

```
gradlew projects
Root project 'MyProject'
+--- Project ':core' - Core module
+--- Project ':App1' - App1
+--- Project ':App2' - APP2
```

Now, I have some dependencies in core module which are using in App1 and App2.
Right now I upgraded dependencies version in core module, it is applied in core module but it wont affected in App1 and App2.

For example:
previously core module has one dependency : quartz-2.3.0

Now I updated it with quartz-2.3.2 in core module, but still it is quartz-2.3.0 in App1 and App2.

Can anyone suggest what issue is this?

Comment: It would help if you shared your Gradle build files.

Comment: Resolved the issue, it was due to gradlle dependency management plugin
io.spring.dependency-management